# Jsoup HTML Parsing with specific tags

Tags: html-parsing, jsoup

I have HTML page with code

`<td class="c" nowrap>993</td>`

i need to parse this and to get 993

I try this code

`doc.select("td.c.nowrap").text()`

but it is doesnt work. Please, type me correct variant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nowrap` is an attribute so it should be enclosed in square brackets (as per the [documentation](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)):

```
Element e = doc.select("td.c[nowrap]").first();
String number = e.text(); // will be 993
```

That will select the first instance of a `<td>` tag that has `class="c"` and the `nowrap` attribute.